# extract data from mixture of code (html, css, javascript) and data

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping, text-parsing, text-extraction, data-extraction

I have some code with data embedded in it. Here's a sample:

```
<div class='clear' ></div>
    </div> <!-- findResultListing -->














    <div class='findResultListing ' id='result_listing_7_0' onclick='examMapManagerHandle.clickMarker(7,0);'>





    <a href='javascript:examMapManagerHandle.clickMarker(7,0);'>
        <img class='balloon' src='/system/themes/asp/img/gmarkerH.png' border='0' />
    </a>


        <div class='findResultInfo'>
                        <div class="nextStep">
                <a href="/system/modules/shibboleth/secure_find/shib_gateway.php?url=%2Fexams%2Fschedule.php%3Fnav%3Dexams%2Cstucourses%2Cexams%2Csched_exam%26amp%3Badd_locid%3D1672">
                    <img height="16" border="0" align="left" width="16" src="/system/themes/asp/img/schedule.png"/>Schedule&nbsp;Exam 
                </a>
            </div>

            <a href='javascript:examMapManagerHandle.clickMarker(7,0);' >


                    SJSU Testing

                    <img class='userType' border='0' src="/system/themes/asp/img/org.png" alt='Testing Site' title='Testing Site'/>




            </a>
            <br />


                                One Washington Square<br />

                                Industrial Studies Building 228<br />

                                San Jose, CA  95112<br />



                                Phone: (408) 924-5980<br />

                                Email: <span id="_smarty_mailto_span_2096382943_1423929156_8">&nbsp;</span>
            <noscript>To see email address, enable javascript</noscript>
            <script type="text/javascript">var mailto=document.getElementById("_smarty_mailto_span_2096382943_1423929156_8");            
               mailto.innerHTML='<a href="mailto:testing-office@sjsu.edu" >testing-office@sjsu.edu</a>';</script><br />




                    Fee for two hour exam: 

        $40.00      












                                <a class="helpBtn" onmouseover="asp_toolTip(this,' &lt;strong&gt;Fee Details:&lt;\/strong&gt; We charge $20 for the first hour and $10 for each half hour after... &lt;br /&gt;  &lt;strong&gt;Miscellaneous Fees:&lt;\/strong&gt; Test emailed in pdf/Word Doc., we will charge an administrative fee of $15 for 10 or more test pages &lt;br /&gt;  &lt;strong&gt;Parking Fee Details:&lt;\/strong&gt; Its $8.00 to park in the 10th St. garage on the corner of 9th &amp; E. San Fernando Sts.', 'findResultsToolTip', 'fit_west', 'map_results_pane');"></a>

            <br />



                            </div><!-- findResultInfo -->
```

I want to extract just the following from the above code:

> SJSU Testing  Testing Site
>
> One Washington Square
>
> Industrial Studies Building 228
>
> San Jose, CA 95112
>
> Phone: (408) 924-5980
>
> Email: testing-office@sjsu.edu
>
> Fee for two hour exam: $40.00

**What are some ways in which I can automate the extraction of this data from the code?**

Comment: does the proposed solution work for you ?

Comment: @aberna I'm not sure how to "use" Xpath. Should I use it from within Chrome (it's available via "inspect element)... or is there some app that I should be using? I'm familiar with Xpath as a technology to locate content in webpages... and have used it from within Excel and Google Sheets --- should I use one of those to do this?

Comment: Xpath is used to navigate elements. All major languages offer different interface to use xpath. Check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath for implementations in the programming language you are comfortable to use.

Comment: Check here on SO for various approaches (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xpath). Since you want to automate the extraction process I suggest you to start make usage of usage of Lxml, BeautifulSoup, Scrapy and more as scrapers for Python

Comment: Thanks -- I just found AquaPath for Mac and am about to try it out. The expression you gave me... is that the same thing as a RegEx?

Comment: You can obtain result both using Xpath and Regex. Much depends of the tools you are going to use to implement the automatization

Comment: @aberna Thanks for your help buddy, I found an online tool that does the job: http://www.webtoolhub.com/tn561393-html-to-text-converter.aspx so I won't have to fiddle with XPath (I don't know it, so it'll be a long time before I figure it out).

Comment: Unusual solution since here people enjoy building things from the scratch with their own hands but it is good that you have found your way.

Answer (score 2):

Using Xpath I would make usage of this expression:

```
//*/text()
```